# How to find all the exact matches in a given string using python Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, search, findall

I am trying to fetch all the 3 character words from my string, but getting only first occurrence

```
import re
a="AAA BBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDD FFF"
print(re.findall('(^[A-Z]{3})',a))
```

Actual output:

```
['AAA']
```

Expected Output is:

```
['AAA','DDD','FFF']
```

Comment: because you are using `^[A-Z]` it will match start of the string only

Comment: @deadshot How can I print all the matches which has exact 3 characters, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^[A-Z]{3}` will match only 3 characters from the start of the string.

Try `re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{3}\b', a)` which will match word boundaries appropriately.